# How to add a framework to iOS library project?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, frameworks, shared-libraries

I have very little experience in native iOS development but my current job is to wrap some specific native iOS framework to use it in React Native.
Preliminary data: common React Native tools generate an empty iOS library project and an example iOS app project that utilizes this library.

First I've tried to add the needed framework directly to the example app using CocoaPods - and it works fine, the framework became a part of linked libPods.a file, then if I add

```
@import MyTargetFramework;
```

to AppDelegate.m I can access different methods of the framework from it.

Next I switched to my iOS library project, applied the same setup (created a Podfile, added the same `pod MyTargetFramework` to it), then added the same `@import MyTargetFramework` to *.m file - but got a build error:

```
Module 'MyTargetFramework' not found
```

Also I've noticed that there is no libPods.a for iOS library project, all the pods are merged to a Pods.framework instead.

So my question is - what am I doing wrong? Why does it work for iOS app project, but not for iOS library project? How can I properly link my target framework to my own iOS library? I've already spent some time googling, but found nothing about app vs lib differences from this point.

Comment: Are there no tutorials explaining this?

Comment: Yep, I understand that my case seems to be pretty basic, but I actually can't find any useful info. All the related posts that I've seen cover a generic case of adding a framework to an _app_ project - the way it works there doesn't work in my case.